# Angular 4 unit testing OKTA SignIn not defined error

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-runner, okta

I am trying to write unit tests in Angular 4. In our application OKTA Sign In is being used. How to mock OKTA Sign in? I am getting an error OktaSignIn not defined

Comment: Can you add some code??

Comment: I'd recommend using a mock object spies. This tutorial on testing Angular apps might help you implement this: http://gist.asciidoctor.org/?github-mraible/ng-demo//README.adoc#_testing

Comment: Thanks both. I have added the answer how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using okta-sign-in.min.js in our index.html. OktaSignIn object is declared in a service as below:

```
declare let OktaSignIn: any;
```

This object is being used in the constructor of the service. During testing this object is not available.

Solution:
As mentioned in this link - https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/27/angular-okta-sign-in-widget instead of including in index.html install the package and use it. One issue I faced not mentioned in the post is overriding Global Promise object of Zone.js. To fix this okta-sign-in-widget should be included before loading zone.js